# File paths of my Laravel project not working the same way on different computer as they do on mine

Tags: php, laravel

I suspect I've been doing file paths the wrong way. On my home computer, I use MAMP and my document root is set to `C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\public` so I just need to go to `localhost:8080` to access the website. On the school computer the document root is set to `C:\wamp\www` so I have to type `localhost:8080\LaravelProject\public` to access the website.

Example #1:

On my home PC, I don't have problem accessing the javascript files located at `C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\public\js` from any URL in my project, however, when I am on the school computer, I can only access the javascript from the index page. If I go to `localhost:8080\LaravelProject\public\images`, I can no longer access the javascript file and everything that requires javascript goes down. The javascript is included in the footer and the footer is included in every page.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/javascript.js"></script>
```

Example #2:

When I am on the school PC, my paths that display the images are not working. For example, if I want this to work:

`<img class='uploadedImg' src='/storage/uploads/images/{{$image->file_name}}' alt='Random image'/>`

I need to remove the `/` before storage but it is working fine on my PC even if the `/` is there.

I can only assume I don't fully understand paths and that is causing these issue.

Comment: `public`  should be your DocumentRoot, you'd need to change that on the school computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using laravel [storage_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-storage-path) helper

`<img class='uploadedImg' src='{{storage_path("uploads/images/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>`

**Updated**

Run the command `php artisan storage:link` it will link your storage director with public and then

`<img class='uploadedImg' src='{{asset("storage/uploads/images/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>`

Comment: Doesn't work, the link I get is C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\storage\uploads/images/Tracer_1519422749.jpg but I need C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\public\storage\uploads/images/Tracer_1519422749.jpg to access the image

Comment: Ok your question was not clear, I've updated my answer now check it